# Efficient way to read big endian data in C#

Tags: c#, endianness, binaryreader

I use the following code to read BigEndian information using `BinaryReader` but I'm not sure if it is the efficient way of doing it. Is there any better solution?

Here is my code:

```
// some code to initialize the stream value
// set the length value to the Int32 size
BinaryReader reader =new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes(length);
Array.Reverse(bytes);
int result = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(temp, 0);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BitConverter.ToInt32` isn't very fast in the first place. I'd simply use

```
public static int ToInt32BigEndian(byte[] buf, int i)
{
  return (buf[i]<<24) | (buf[i+1]<<16) | (buf[i+2]<<8) | buf[i+3];
}
```

You could also consider reading more than 4 bytes at a time.

Comment: thanks It's very interesting but to be sure that I got the idea correctly, can you explain how we can read more than 4 bytes.

Comment: Just call `ReadBytes` with a larger length, and then use different `i`s to read integers at different positions in the array. But that's an optimization you should only take after benchmarking.

Comment: Yes, I've used something like this for some of my projects (albeit not in C#).  But I had expected BinaryReader/Writer to have endian control built in, which would make it much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2019 (in fact, since .net core 2.1), there is now

```cs
byte[] buffer = ...;

BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(buffer.AsSpan());
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives.readint32bigendian)

[Implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/65dc73a6018d4e694e3ddb5d403ef6de1e1138eb/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Binary/ReaderBigEndian.cs#L30)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder.aspx), but I have no idea if it's actually more efficient. You'd have to profile it.