# Bitwise endian swap for various types

Tags: c#, .net

With the help of various sources, I have written some `SwapBytes` methods in my binary reader class that swap endian in `ushort`, `uint`, and `ulong`, all using bitwise operations all in raw C# with no need for any `unsafe` code.

```
public ushort SwapBytes(ushort x)
{
    return (ushort)((ushort)((x & 0xff) << 8) | ((x >> 8) & 0xff));
}

public uint SwapBytes(uint x)
{
    return ((x & 0x000000ff) << 24) +
           ((x & 0x0000ff00) << 8) +
           ((x & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) +
           ((x & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

public ulong SwapBytes(ulong value)
{
    ulong uvalue = value;
    ulong swapped =
         ((0x00000000000000FF) & (uvalue >> 56)
         | (0x000000000000FF00) & (uvalue >> 40)
         | (0x0000000000FF0000) & (uvalue >> 24)
         | (0x00000000FF000000) & (uvalue >> 8)
         | (0x000000FF00000000) & (uvalue << 8)
         | (0x0000FF0000000000) & (uvalue << 24)
         | (0x00FF000000000000) & (uvalue << 40)
         | (0xFF00000000000000) & (uvalue << 56));
    return swapped;
}
```

How would i go about creating the same methods but for the signed versions of each of these types, such as short, int and long, Using only the same methods as above, and what improvements could be made to the methods above?

Comment: Why do you need to swap in the first place? Couldn't you directly read using desired endianness from the input byte array? In my experience that leads to faster, easier to read and easier to test code.

Comment: Nowadays there is `BinaryPrimitives.ReverseEndianness`.

Comment: @greenoldman this new standard way. Maybe add this as an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of conceptually deconstructing to separate bytes and then reassembling them the other way around, you can conceptually swap groups of bytes, like this: (not tested)

```
public uint SwapBytes(uint x)
{
    // swap adjacent 16-bit blocks
    x = (x >> 16) | (x << 16);
    // swap adjacent 8-bit blocks
    return ((x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8);
}
```

Doesn't help much (or at all) for 32 bits, but for 64 bits it does (not tested)

```
public ulong SwapBytes(ulong x)
{
    // swap adjacent 32-bit blocks
    x = (x >> 32) | (x << 32);
    // swap adjacent 16-bit blocks
    x = ((x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16) | ((x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16);
    // swap adjacent 8-bit blocks
    return ((x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8);
}
```

For signed types, just cast to unsigned, do this, then cast back.

Comment: And *please* keep the comments. I know I'd be quite puzzled before figuring out what those bitmasks and shifting around was good for!

Answer (score 11):

You should have a look to following msdn page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

You may simply use Array.Reverse and bitConverter:

```
  int value = 12345678;
  byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

  Array.Reverse(bytes); 
  int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

Comment: As i said, i would like to use bitwise operators rather than converting between types and swapping around arrays

Comment: This is certainly going to be much slower than the code the OP has given. You can benchmark it and see.

Comment: `BitConverter` uses native endianness, is slow and the `Array.Reverse` spams  an unnecessary instance making it even slower.

Comment: Fine. I don't realy want to benchmark it. I believe you. It's just a short (and easily maintainable) way to write it in case performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness -- nowadays there is `BinaryPrimitives.ReverseEndianness`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a cast to unsigned at the start and back to signed at the end.

```
public long SwapBytes(long value)
{
    return (long)SwapBytes((ulong)value);
}
```

It might be necessary to manually inline the call to `SwapBytes` for maximal performance.

---

On a different note, you might want to avoid swapping, in favour of directly reading the data from the original byte array in the desired endianness. See [Efficient way to read big endian data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401270/efficient-way-to-read-big-endian-data-in-c-sharp) for details.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably the easiest and lazy way to replace bits in an integer:

```
using System;

namespace BitSwap
{
  class Program    
  {
    static void Main()        
    {
        //swaps bits {p, p+1, …, p+k-1} with bits {q, q+1, …, q+k-1} of n.
        Console.WriteLine("n=");
        uint n = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("p=");
        int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("q=");
        int q = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("k=");
        int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i;
        int s;
        if ((p + k - 1) < 32 && (q + k - 1) < 32 && p > 0 && q > 0)
        // for integer
        {
            for (i = p, s = q; i <= p + k - 1 && s <= q + k - 1; i++, s++)
            {
                uint firstBits = (n >> i) & 1;
                uint secondBits = (n >> s) & 1;
                uint maskFirstBits = (uint)1 << i;
                uint maskSecondBits = (uint)1 << s;
                n = (n & ~maskFirstBits) | (secondBits << i);
                n = (n & ~maskSecondBits) | (firstBits << s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", n);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.");
        }
     }
   }
 }
```