# Reverse Byte Orders

Tags: c#, byte

For Example :

I am trying to do this: 0x64CEED7E becomes 7EEDCE64.

This is my code.

```
for (int integerTemp = 0; integerTemp < 4; integerTemp++)
{
   generatedKey[integerTemp] = Convert.ToByte(((uint)(integerkey & (0x000000FF   << (integerTemp * 8)))) >> (integerTemp * 8));
}
```

What is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise endian swap for various types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560436/bitwise-endian-swap-for-various-types)

Comment: You can use this : static uint Convert(uint input)
        {
            return
                ((input & 0x000000ffU) << 24) +
                ((input & 0x0000ff00U) << 8) +
                ((input & 0x00ff0000U) >> 8) +
                ((input & 0xff000000U) >> 24);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `BitConverter` class:

```
int key = 0x64CEED7E;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(key);
Array.Reverse(bytes);
key = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

Console.WriteLine(key.ToString("x"));
```