# Reversing Endianess C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, endianness

I'm lost on bit shifting operations, I'm trying to reverse byte order on 32 bit ints, what I've managed to look up online I only got this far but cant seem to find why its not working

```
int32_t swapped = 0;         //  Assign num to the tmp 


for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{

   swapped |= num & 1; // putting the set bits of num

   swapped >>= 1; //shift the swapped Right side 

   num <<= 1;  //shift the swapped left side 

}
```

And I'm printing like this

```
num = swapped;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    printf("%d",(num >> i));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitwise endian swap for various types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560436/bitwise-endian-swap-for-various-types)

Comment: You're shifting in the wrong direction in both cases

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks likes its attempting to swap bits, and ***not bytes***. If you are wanting to swap bytes, then the 'complete' method would be:

```cpp
int32_t swapped = ((num >> 24) & 0x000000FF) |
                  ((num >>  8) & 0x0000FF00) |
                  ((num <<  8) & 0x00FF0000) |
                  ((num << 24) & 0xFF000000);
```

I say 'complete', because the last bitwise-and can be omitted, and the first bitwise-and can be omitted *if num is unsigned*.

If you want to swap ***the bits*** in a 32bit number, your loop should probably max out at 16 (if it's 32, the first 16 steps will swap the bits, the next 16 steps will swap them back again).

```cpp
int32_t swapped = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
  // the masks for the two bits (hi and lo) we will be swapping
  // shift a '1' to the correct bit location based on the index 'i'
  uint32_t hi_mask = 1 << (31 - i);
  uint32_t lo_mask = 1 << i;

  // use bitwise and to mask out the original bits in the number
  uint32_t hi_bit = num & hi_mask;
  uint32_t lo_bit = num & lo_mask;

  // shift the bits so they switch places
  uint32_t new_lo_bit = hi_bit >> (31 - i);
  uint32_t new_hi_bit = lo_bit << (31 - i);

  // use bitwise-or to combine back into an int
  swapped |= new_lo_bit;
  swapped |= new_hi_bit;
}
```

Code written for readability - there are faster ways to reverse the bits in a 32bit number. As for printing:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    bool bit = (num >> (31 - i)) & 0x1;
    printf(bit ? "1" : "0");
}
```