# How to convert byte array to int32

Tags: c#

Please help me to convert byte array in to int32 using c#.

I used the following code but did not get the exact value

```
byte[] newArray3 = new[] { buffer[m+2], buffer[m+3], buffer[m], buffer[m+1] }; 
int t = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray3,0);
```

Thanks in advance.

```
      *15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8* * 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0**
```

Word1 ...**S** msb ....**buffer[m+1]**..  . .........**buffer[m].................**

word2 .....**buffer[m+3]**...........................**.buffer[m+2]......... lsb**

Comment: Similar question: [Efficient way to read big endian data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401270/efficient-way-to-read-big-endian-data-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What are the values in `buffer[m]` through `buffer[m+3]`, and what do you expect the returned value to be?

Answer (score 4):

use bitshifting instead

```
m[0] << 24 || m[1] << 16 || m[2] << 8 || m[3]
```

assumes m[0] contains MSB...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to change the MSB position, use

```
BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, m);
```

There's no need to copy the data to another byte array in-between.

If you do need to change the endianness, you're stuck with using bitshifting as LB2 suggested above.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You can always check if the hardware is the endianness you want and only use the manual bit ORing if it doesn't suit your needs.