# Convert uint[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, cryptography

I'm working on cryptography algorithm and I need to convert initialization vector from uint[] to byte[]:

```cs
public byte[] IV { get; set; }

....

uint[] vector = new uint[256] { 0x95ae2518, 0x6fff22fc ...... };
int i=-1;
foreach (uint vec in vector)
{
   IV[++i] = Convert.ToByte(vec);
}
```

That's not working - it sais that uint is too large to be converted to byte.
So how do you convert from uint[] to byte[]?

Comment: @adrift not a single answer over there is correct for this question since they use native endianness.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401270/efficient-way-to-read-big-endian-data-in-c-sharp or the little endian equivalent.